# Bulk hash insert with multiple Hash Key value using StackExchange.Redis

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

i am using Redis server - 4.0.9 , StackExchange.Redis (2.2.4).

i am trying to insert my csv data into Redis hash CSV contain ~10K Record and file size is 2 mb.
its take around  17 second to push 10k record.

**Here is all my Test Result -**

1. simple Key, value pair  Process Time for ~100k Record ->   8 Second
   using StringSetAsync.
2. Hash Key with 2 pair Process Time sec ~100k Record ->   14 Second
   HashSetAsync.
3. Hash Key CSV Process Time sec ~10K Record ->   17 Second

I am using pipelining for process this record .

```
 public class Redis_Test
{
    private static ConfigurationOptions _configurationOptions;
    public Redis_Test(string argStrEndPoints)
    {
        _configurationOptions = new ConfigurationOptions
        {

            EndPoints = { argStrEndPoints },
            AbortOnConnectFail = false,
            KeepAlive = 60

        };
    }

    public Redis_Test(string argStrEndPoints, string argStrPassword)
    {
        _configurationOptions = new ConfigurationOptions
        {

            EndPoints = { argStrEndPoints },
            Password = argStrPassword,
            AbortOnConnectFail = false,
            KeepAlive = 60

        };
    }

    private static IDatabase RedisCache
    {
        get
        {
            return Connection.GetDatabase();
        }
    }

    private static readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> LazyConnection
        = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(_configurationOptions));

    public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
    {
        get
        {
            return LazyConnection.Value;
        }
    }


    public void testpipe()
    {

        List<Task> redisTask = new List<Task>();
        int batch = 10000;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100000; i++)
        {

            Task<bool> addAsyncTask = RedisCache.StringSetAsync("testKey:" + i.ToString(), "Value:" + i.ToString());
            redisTask.Add(addAsyncTask);

            if (i == batch)
            {
                Task[] TaskArray = redisTask.ToArray();
                Task.WaitAll(TaskArray);

                redisTask.Clear();
                batch = batch + 10000;


            }
        }

    }
    public void testpipehash()
    {

        List<Task> redisTask = new List<Task>();
        int batch = 10000;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100000; i++)
        {
            HashEntry[] ab = new HashEntry[] { new HashEntry("hash1"+ i.ToString(), "hashvalue1"+i.ToString()),
                new HashEntry("hash2" + i.ToString(), "hashvalue2" + i.ToString()) };
            Task addAsyncTask = RedisCache.HashSetAsync("testhashKey:" + i.ToString(), ab);
            redisTask.Add(addAsyncTask);

            if (i == batch)
            {
                Task[] TaskArray = redisTask.ToArray();
                Task.WaitAll(TaskArray);

                redisTask.Clear();
                batch = batch + 10000;


            }
        }

    }

    public int testpipehashCSV(DataTable dataTable)
    {

        List<Task> redisTask = new List<Task>();
        int batch = 1000;

        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            // converting row to dic
            watch.Stop();

            Dictionary<string, string> test = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            test = dr.Table.Columns
                        .Cast<DataColumn>()
                        .ToDictionary(c => c.ColumnName, c => dr[c].ToString());


            //converting dic to hashentry[]
            var hashEntries = test.Select(
                       Pair => new HashEntry(Pair.Key, Pair.Value)).ToArray();

            watch.Start();

            Task addAsyncTask = RedisCache.HashSetAsync("testhashKeyCSV:" + i.ToString(), hashEntries);
            redisTask.Add(addAsyncTask);

            if (i == batch)
            {
                Task[] TaskArray = redisTask.ToArray();
                Task.WaitAll(TaskArray);

                redisTask.Clear();
                batch = batch + 1000;


            }
            i++;

        }
        watch.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts = watch.Elapsed;

        int totaltimeinsec = ts.Seconds;
        return totaltimeinsec;

    }
}
```

Please any suggestion where i can improve my CSV file data load into Redis Hash.

Thanks.